# How do I run npm package commands on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm-install, heroku-cli

I am using [node-mongo-seeds](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mongo-seeds) in my express app to seed data. I deployed the app to Heroku and SSHed into the dyno, but running 'seed' command gives me command not found.

Comment: Could you show what your package.json looks like? This would happen for sure if node-mongo-seeds isn't in your dependencies.

Comment: I am pretty amazed by the quick response over here within minutes of posting. Yes you were right. I did not have it my package.json. I made the changes and it works. However I get "No key exists in seed.json for the passed in NODE_ENV" error on Heroku.